# Create vector with position of value from highest to lowest

Tags: r

I have a vector:

```
set.seed(12)
a<-rnorm(4)
```

I would like to create a another vector that codes the position of the largest, second largest...smallest value in `a`.

An example:

```
>a
[1] -1.4805676  1.5771695 -0.9567445 -0.9200052
```

The desired vector would be: `2 4 3 1`

Is there a function for doing this?

Comment: use `order(a, decreasing= TRUE)`

Comment: Or simpler, `order(-a)`

Answer (score 0):

Posting @DavidArenburg's answer here to close out the question.

If you have the vector

```
 a<-c(-1.4805676,  1.5771695, -0.9567445, -0.9200052)
```

then

```
order(-a)
# [1] 2 4 3 1
```

will give you the desired value.